# Blazor @attribute [Authorize] tag is not working

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, blazor

I have a working .NET Core 3.0 MVC website, using AzureAD for authentication, this all works fine. I have started to migrate some of the front-end pages to Blazor (in same project) but cannot get authentication to work.

I have added the @attribute [Authorize] tag to the top of Index.razor but I do not get redirected to Azure to login as I would do when adding it to a standard ASP.NET MVC Controller.

Startup.ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    Configuration.GetSection("OpenIdConnect").Bind(options);
});
services.AddAuthorizationCore(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(Policies.AccessRole, Policies.IsAccessPolicy());
    options.AddPolicy(Policies.AdminRole, Policies.IsAdminPolicy());
});
```

Startup.Configure

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = Policies.AccessRole)]
```

Policies

```
public static class Policies
{
    public const string AccessRole = "Access";
    public const string AdminRole = "Admin";

    public static AuthorizationPolicy IsAccessPolicy()
    {
        return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                               .RequireRole(AccessRole)
                                               .Build();
    }

    public static AuthorizationPolicy IsAdminPolicy()
    {
        return new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                               .RequireRole(AdminRole)
                                               .Build();
    }
}
```

If I navigate to an MVC page I get authenticated by AzureAD, if I then return to the Blazor page I can use the following successfuly

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="@Policies.AccessRole">
    <p>Is in Access policy.</p>
</AuthorizeView>

<AuthorizeView Policy="@Policies.AdminRole">
    <p>Is in Admin policy.</p>
</AuthorizeView>
```

So to summarise, my Blazor page is not automatically issuing the auth challenge when using the [Authorize] attribute.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

It's as designed
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13709

As a workaround I have added a component to redirect to a login page

App.razor

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <AuthChallenge></AuthChallenge>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <CascadingAuthenticationState>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </CascadingAuthenticationState>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

AuthCallenge.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("/Account/SignIn", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Dave, I came across the same problem, I am wondering if you've solved?

Comment: Hi, I just have it working as above under 'Update'

Comment: I've solved too by creating a custom AuthenticationStateProvider

Answer (score 26):

Take a look at your App.razor file. Do you use RouteView or AuthorizeRouteView?

You need to define an AuthorizeRouteView as described on the ["ASP.NET Core Blazor authentication and authorization" page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component).

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <NotAuthorized>
            <h1>Sorry</h1>
            <p>You're not authorized to reach this page.</p>
            <p>You may need to log in as a different user.</p>
        </NotAuthorized>
        <Authorizing>
            <h1>Authentication in progress</h1>
            <p>Only visible while authentication is in progress.</p>
        </Authorizing>
    </AuthorizeRouteView>
</Found>
<NotFound>
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <h1>Sorry</h1>
            <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</NotFound>
```

Seems like the AuthorizeAttribute doesn't do all that much if that component is missing.

Comment: I have an AuthorizeRouteView, still didn't work. I've just added the Update section to the post to show a work-around

Comment: Another day lost because I didn't see the RouteView needed to be an AuthorizedRouteView. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You must use CascadingAuthenticationState as root in the XML

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(EmptyLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <h1>404 Error</h1>
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  config.AddPolicy("InAdminGroup",
                     Policies.InAdminGroup()
                     );

    config.AddPolicy("InApproverGroup",
                     Policies.InApproverGroup()
                     );

    config.AddPolicy("InInvestigatorGroup",
                     Policies.InInvestigatorGroup()
                     );
```